# Возможно ли сделать мою активность которая будет запускатся первой и принимать intent данные?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Здравствуйте я хочу узнать возможно ли сделать так чтобы моя активность запускалась первой и могла также принимать какие-то данные от другого приложения. Но когда я делаю то как показано ниже в моём манифесте то приложения исчезает из списка приложений и есть только при отправке данных:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="add">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Если можно так сделать то как? Заранее спасибо.
P.S. Могу предвидеть альтернативный вариант: "сделать другую стартовую активность которая при входе сразу будет перебрасывать в нужную вам активность и с помощью `finish()` завершать работу стартовой активности" мне это не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Нет, так нельзя сделать, по любому, если в системе есть несколько приложений поддерживающих пересылку текстовых файлов (`text/plain`), то при первом запуске юзеру будет предъявлен список приложений, из которых юзер выберет сам.
2. Вам надо посадить каждый `action` на раздельный `intent-filter`, типа:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение буду знать